# How is EMF of cell independent of external resistance (resistance of circuit) and current drawn?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Emf is the work done to move a charge across the whole circuit. If i have a resistor wont the work done to move the unit charge increase?

Answer (score 1):

> How is emf of cell independent of external resistance(resistance of
>   circuit) and current drawn?

The emf of the cell is the electrical potential (voltage) developed within the cell due to electro-chemical reactions. It is ideally independent of the external resistance of a circuit and the current drawn. The voltage across the terminals of the cell, $V_T$, is not. That's because all real batteries have internal resistance $r_b$. When current is drawn by the circuit there is a voltage drop across the internal resistance resulting in a lower terminal voltage.

The top diagram below shows an "ideal" battery, that is, a battery with zero internal resistance. The terminal voltage $V_T$ equals the internal battery emf regardless of the external load resistance $R_L$ and current drawn.

The bottom diagram shows a "real" battery with internal resistance $r_b$. When current $I$ is drawn there is a voltage drop $Ir_b$ across the internal resistance resulting in a lower voltage at the battery terminals. The battery has to do work internally to overcome its internal resistance.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The EMF of an ideal battery is constant, what will happen is that the current through the resistor will decrease.

Answer (score 0):

If V=IR is the p.d across the resistor, then this is the same for emf $\epsilon=IR$ if only the resistor is connected to the battery and ideal conditions. If we know emf is constant, then ohms law tells us that the current must decrease. So no, work done to move a unit charge does not change. I think its useful to compare to gravity, if you jump off a tree, the amount of potential energy you have at the top(like emf in the cell) is what will be lost by the time you hit the ground.